# caffe learned convolutional filters are random

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I've designed a simple network with 1 convolutional layer, 1 pooling layer, 2 fully connected layers and a softmax output layer. The network is a binary classifier and it performs with an accuracy of around 80%. I wanted to know what the filters were learning so followed this ipython notebook: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/rc2/examples/filter_visualization.ipynb. Here are the layer features and their shapes:

```
[('data', (1, 3, 64, 64)),
 ('conv1', (1, 48, 55, 55)),
 ('pool1', (1, 48, 27, 27)),
 ('ip1', (1, 500)),
 ('ip2', (1, 2)),
 ('prob', (1, 2))]
```

And here is the filter visualisation:

[image]

I can't work out why they haven't learnt anything even though the convnet is successful in it's classification. Any advice/reasoning would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Example of image (class 1):
[image]

Example of image (class 0):
[image]

Comment: are you sure you loaded the trained parameters before visualizing the filters?

Comment: how many training examples do you have? how many validation examples? how are the training/validation examples split among the two classes, 50/50?

Comment: The classification is binary. I have around 1400 images split pretty much 50/50, train/val is 75/25. I loaded the last snapshot of the caffemodel and corresponding deploy file. The images are ground penetrating radargrams (B-scans).

Comment: how does your typical image look like? is it possible that your model captured some noise patterns and did the classification accordingly?

Comment: @shai see edit. The hyperbola in the first image is the discriminator

Comment: the vertical columns artifacts in the images introduce high frequencies that might interfere with learning local filters of lower frequencies. can you try smoothing the input images and re-train?

Comment: will re-process the images and see what happens. could you elaborate when you say "introduce high frequencies"

Comment: If you look at the image in [frequency domain (Fourier domain)](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/what-does-frequency-domain-denote-in-case-of-images) you will note that, unlike "natural images", your images have very dominant high frequencies due to the vertical "stripes" artifacts. I suspect these high frequencies causes the learning process not to focus on "regular"/"natural" filters that usually captures relatively low/medium frequency aspects of the image (e.g., blobs/edges etc.)

Comment: I re-trained the net on the smoothed images but still got the same random filter pattern.... It was suggest on the caffe-users group that i redesign the net with sets of smaller, 3x3 conv filters as per the VGG caffe network. The theory being that most of the learning was being done in the fully connected layer with 500 neurons. I also did this and the filters remain 'random'.

Comment: does smoothing the images improved the accuracy?

Comment: No -  but after deepening the network and tinkering with hyper-parameters yes....

Comment: @Shai any other suggestions? could it be that because the two classes are quite similar there is only a vague classification boundary?